# What is the ideal way to ask/response on jsperf related question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Related to comments on
[JSPerf, For Loop vs While Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366388/jsperf-for-loop-vs-while-loop#34366388)

Do you need to simulate the whole jsperf benchmark functionality inside SO question as code other than linking to jsperf entry?

If you think I am not posting code in my answer, checkout [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34366427/revisions)

If https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve have some suggestion about performance benchmarking question, it would be great.

Comment: In my opinion, those comments/down votes on your answer are uncalled for. If anything, I'd just include the `for` loop snippet in your answer and explicitly state that they have the same performance. Without clicking the JSperf link, it is somewhat ambiguous when you said "*same performance*".